# Deletar item da lista se diretório não existir

Tags: python, loop

Eu tenho uma lista contendo o caminho de alguns diretórios, quero verificar se cada diretório existe, para isso utilizo o `os.path.exists()`, se um diretório não existe, uso o método `remove()` para remove-lo da lista, porém no looping `for` ele ignora o próximo item da lista, por exemplo, se o `a:/` não existe ele o paga porém pula o `b:/` e apaga o `c:/` e assim por diante.

Segue o código que estou usando:

```
def conf_dir_exist_b(lines):
    for lna in lines:
        for lnb in lna:
            if(os.path.exists(lnb) == False):
                lna.remove(lnb)
            else:
                pass
    return lines

if __name__ == '__main__':
conf_dir_exist_b(['a:/', 'b:/', 'w:/', 'g:/', 'f:/', 'd:/Downloads/Torrent/End', 'x:/files.2t', 'y:/files.1t'], ['d:/Dropbox/project/rato_bat', 'x:/bb'])
```

Comment: Não entendi qual é a dúvida

Comment: ok, porque acontece de quando apago um idem da lista por exemplo: `lista = [['a:/', 'b:/', 'c:/'], ['d:/', 'e:/']]` irei remover o elemento `'a:/'` dentro de um looping `for` entoa uso o `lista.remove('a:/')` porem no próximo ciclo do `for` ele ignora o `b:/` e remove o `c:/`. compreende?

Comment: Ah sim, eu que não li direito, obrigado

Comment: @Nasca Aquele código que eu postei funcionou?

Comment: Não faça comparaçoes de igualdade com os valreos "True" ou "False" - o `if` sozinho já testa esses valores. A forma mais "bonita" é:
`if not os.path.exists(lnb) == False:`  (aliás, Python não precisa de parenteses na expressão do if)

Comment: @zekk então ainda nem tive tempo de ver direito mas resolveu porem achei que o script se tornou muito extensivo para pouca coisa.

Comment: @Nasca 7 linhas, não é tanta coisa assim, também tem aquele outro modo, veja o último código lá em baixo. :)

Comment: @zekk não digo em relação a seu modo ele e pratico rápido e elegante, mas o meu código em um geral ficou extensos pretendo reavaliar algumas funcionalidades do script para deixa-lo mais enxuto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) isso acontece porque:

> (Em tradução livre)
>
> Há uma sutileza quando a sequência está sendo modificado pelo loop
>   (isso só pode ocorrer por sequências mutáveis, isto é, *listas*). Um
>   contador interno é usado para manter o controle de qual item é usado
>   seguinte, e este é incrementado a cada iteração. Quando este contador
>   tiver atingido o comprimento da sequência o *loop* termina.
>
> **Isto significa que se o conjunto exclui o item atual (ou um anterior)
>   da sequência, o próximo item será ignorado (uma vez que obtém o
>   índice do item atual que já foi tratado**).
>
> Da mesma forma, se o conjunto insere um item na seqüência antes do item
>   atual, o item atual será tratado novamente na próxima vez através do
>   *loop*. Isso pode levar a bugs que podem ser evitados fazendo uma cópia
>   temporária usando uma fatia de toda a sequência, [...]

Uma forma de você fazer isto é percorrer toda a lista e verificar se o item atual é um diretório existente, se for, você o insere em uma nova lista, ao término da iteração você devolve como resultado essa lista, veja um exemplo:

```
def checkDirExist(lista):
    # Variável que vai armazenar os diretórios existentes
    resultado = []

    # Percorre cada uma das listas
    for diretorios in lista:
        # Percorre os itens das listas
        for diretorio in diretorios:
            # Verifica se o item atual é um diretório existente
            if os.path.exists(diretorio):
                # Se for, armazena o item na nova lista
                resultado.append(diretorio)
            # Caso não exista o diretório   
            #else:
            #   print("O diretório {0} não existe!".format(diretorio))

    return resultado

# Lista de listas
diretorios = [
               ['a:/', 'b:/', 'w:/', 'g:/', 'f:/',
                'd:/Downloads/Torrent/End', 'x:/files.2t', 'y:/files.1t'], 
               ['d:/Dropbox/project/rato_bat', 'x:/bb'],
             ]

diretoriosExistentes = checkDirExist(diretorios)

# ... continuação do teu código ...
```

Uma outra forma é usar [*List Comprehensions*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), que consiste em criar uma nova lista com os itens que você quer:

```
diretorios[:] = [listas for listas in diretorios for dir in listas if os.path.exists(dir)]
print (diretorios)
```